# obtaining each instance of a substing between two other substrings

Tags: java, string, search, substring

for a program im writing ive stored information from a html file within a string. the html file is an exported bookmark file and i need my program to search through the html file and store each instance a bookmark to a specific site so that i can do further processing.

the bookmarks have a consistent start but don't have a consistent end e.g.

```
https://www.example.net/e/1111111/1/example
https://www.example.net/e/2222222/1/
https://www.example.net/e/3333333/1
https://www.example.net/e/4444444
```

in the html file after the url is a quotation mark but im unsure how to use this to grab the url.

if anyone could point me in the right direction id appreciate it

@mafagafogigante thx for the help it allowed me to generate the following code:

```
public static void FileforURL(String content){
    int first, second;

   while(content.indexOf("https://www.example.net/e/") != -1){
        first = content.indexOf("https://www.example.net/e/");
        if(content.indexOf("\"",first) != -1){
            second = content.indexOf("\"",first);

            try {
                URL(content.substring(first, second));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            content = content.substring(second,content.length());
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String.indexOf(...) to get the next "https:// [...]" substring start.

Repeat the find the start of the next substring you want.

Get the text in between.

Repeat until you get a -1, all that remains is your last URL.